# Using Chrome Developer Tools to Get Favicon

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

When I try to hit my test webpage, I get a 503 error.

In the browser tab, the icon associated with my page. However, when I use Chrome Developer Tools, I don't see how that image is appearing.

I cleared my cache prior to hitting the page. Also, I had looked at the HTML and Network tabs, but do not see how the file is getting retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still an issue.  See [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=110449).  It has been pushed off for some time.